# Flutter : Textfield in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter

Hi everyone i have some data at Cloud Firestore and a ListView.builder to load the data in it. In this ListView.builder i have Network.Image, ListTile to show the title and subtitle and another ListTile which has a Textfield to add some comment and an iconbutton. My goal is to get the text of the textfield and show as a alertDialog when the button clicked. Until now i added a controller to the textfield but whenever i type anything in the textfield it changes all the textfields. I have tried creating a List to specify a unique controller so i can stop the all of the changes in textfields but i have failed. Is there any way i can do this. All this textfields and iconbuttons must be unique so when i clicked the iconbutton i need to see the text of the typed textfield.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try using

```
List<TextEditingController> _controllers = new List();
//try below in null-safe
//List<TextEditingController>? _controllers = [];
```

And inside your `ListView.builder` add a new controller for each item.

```
ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context,index){
              _controllers.add(new TextEditingController());
              //try below in null-safe
              //_controllers!.add(TextEditingController());
              //Your code here

            }),
```

To access the controller's text you will need the index value

`_controllers[index].text`

Make sure to dispose of all textControllers in the end.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ashutosh u saved my day m8

Comment: how do you dispose this list of text controllers?

Comment: To dispose of the text controllers I'm putting this in my dispose() function: `for (TextEditingController c in _controllers) {
      c.dispose();
    }`

Comment: i don't know how is your answer is right one 

your code will create new controller every scroll and recreate item in list ! and length of controller won't be the same as length of your list

Comment: how would you implement the same answer on a nested listview.builder?

Answer (score 7):

You might want to consider making a **new type of custom Widget for each row**.

You can leverage a

- `TextEditingController` (where you call the corresponding controller
  `on click` or the
- `TextField`'s `onChanged` callback (where you store the new value for
  the corresponding item `on change`

In both cases you have a somewhat **nasty list of either text controllers or String values**.

Remember, [ListView.builder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) is only going to build the items that are in or near the viewport (as you scroll).

> the builder is called only for those children that are actually visible

That means that you can have the **same row built multiple times** (

**Consider using a custom widget for each row** (extend `StatefulWidget`)

*This will alleviate the coordination involved with all the roles and it will push any resulting state further down the tree to the leaf nodes*

If using a `TextEditingController`:

- you only have one controller to worry
- call `_textController.dispose()` in the widget's `dispose()` method

If using a [onChanged](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextField/onChanged.html) callback (available on `TextField` not `TextFormField`)

- create a String variable as state in the custom widget `inputValue`
- handle the null cases
- read from this when the button is tapped

---

It looks like the TextEditingController may be easiest, but I wanted to mention both options for your consideration.

Comment: how to dispose controller in listview.builder?

Answer (score 2):

```
ListView.builder(
         shrinkWrap: true,
         physics: ScrollPhysics(),
         itemCount: list.length,
         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
         _controllers.add(new TextEditingController());
           return Container(
               child: TextField(
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  controller:   _controllers[index],
                  autofocus: false,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,),))
```

Comment: how do you set a controller on a listview.builder like this but nested?