# The TextFields in ListView.builder are disappearing

Tags: flutter, listview, texteditingcontroller

To do an Inventory Control, I'm building a ListView from Firebase Data (a list of "Alimentos") and a TextField to edit the quantity for each "Alimento".

It's working fine when I have less than a screen of "Alimentos", but when I have some pages of "Alimentos", my textfields are disappearing. I understand it happens because ListView.builder is only going to build the items that are in or near the viewport (as you scroll), but I don't know how to solve it.

I read [Textfield in ListView.builder Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234378/flutter-textfield-in-listview-builder), where @Ashton Thomas suggests to implemment a Custom Widget per Row, but I don't understand how to get that.

This is my ListView.Builder...

```
  Widget _crearListado(BuildContext context, AlimentoBloc alimentoBloc) {

    final _size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Container(
      height: _size.height * 0.5,
      child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: alimentoBloc.alimentoStream ,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<AlimentoModel>> snapshot){
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              List<AlimentoModel> alimentos = snapshot.data;
              alimentos.sort((a, b) => a.proteina.compareTo(b.proteina));
              return Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: alimentos.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) { //Esta variable es gráfica, sólo se crea para lo que se está viendo
                      _controlList.add(new ControlInventarioModel());
                      return _crearItem(context, alimentoBloc, alimentos[i], i);
                    },

                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 0.0, bottom: 20.0),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            } else {
              return Center (child: Image(image: AssetImage('assets/Aplians-fish-Preloader.gif'), height: 200.0,));
            }
          },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Each row has an Item (_CrearItem) with an a TextField on its trailing (_cajaNum) as following:

```
  Widget _crearItem(BuildContext context, AlimentoBloc alimentoBloc, AlimentoModel alimento, int i) {

      return Card(
        color: Colors.grey[200], //color de la tarjeta
        elevation: 0.0, //sin sombra
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
        child: ListTile(
            title: Text('${alimento.nombre}', style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontSize: 18.0)),
            subtitle: Text ('${alimento.fabricante}'), //refLoteActual
            onTap: () {},
            leading: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.shoppingBag, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
            trailing: _cajaNum(context, i, alimento.idAlimento),// nuevoControlador),
        ),
      );
  }

  Widget _cajaNum(BuildContext context, int i, String idAlimento){    
    return Container(
      width: 100.0,
      height: 40.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: TextField(
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(),//decimal:false, signed: false),
        inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^(\d+)?\.?\d{0,2}')),
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.singleLineFormatter,
            ],
        maxLength: 5,
        onChanged: (value) {
                if(utils.isNumeric(value) && double.parse(value)>=0) {
                  _controlList[i].cantControl = double.parse(value);
                } 
                else {
                  _controlList[i].cantControl = null;
                }
                },
        onEditingComplete: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },
        onSubmitted: (value) {
        },
      ),
    ); 
  }
```

If my ListView continuously rebuilds on scroll, how can I keep the values of TextFields?

**UPDATE**

I include screenshots that show textfields "disappearing"...

[image: Textfields Disappearing in ListView]

Comment: can you provide some screenshot on your UI?

Comment: @John Joe I just attached an animated gif to clarify  Thank you

Comment: try adding textEditingController to controller property of TextField

Answer (score 1):

For this problem you need to understand the widget life cycle of ListView.builder. See:
[https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html#:~:text=Child%20elements%27%20lifecycle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html#:%7E:text=Child%20elements%27%20lifecycle)

> **Destruction**

> When a child is scrolled out of view, the associated
> element subtree, states and render objects are destroyed. A new child
> at the same position in the list will be lazily recreated along with
> new elements, states and render objects when it is scrolled back.

**So, how do we stop Flutter from destroying our precious subtree and state?**

With the `AutoMaticKeepAliveClientMixin` :)

Extend your state class with this mixin as follows:

```
class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomepage> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin
```

Then you must do two things:

Add the `wantKeepAlive` override:

```
@override   
bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
```

Then add:

```
super.build(context);
```

Just under the build method that you want to preserve.

If there is a scenario where you know longer require the state to be preserved you can set:

```
bool get wantKeepAlive => false;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

add property TextFormField : `initialValue`.
its worked for me, I also experienced the same thing.

like this

```
TextField(
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
    initialValue: _controlList[i].cantControll ?? '0',
    onChanged: (value) {
            if(utils.isNumeric(value) && double.parse(value)>=0) {
              _controlList[i].cantControl = double.parse(value);
            } 
            else {
              _controlList[i].cantControl = null;
            }
            },
    onEditingComplete: () {
      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    },
    onSubmitted: (value) {
    },
  ),
```

cause, your textfield rebuild when you scroll and input next texfield.
but your data is already stored in `_controlList[i].cantControl`.